# Strong closure of a C*-algebra of operators.

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In Arveson's book, the Kaplansky density theorem is proved in order to have this corollary: "Let $A$ be a self-adjoint algebra of operators on a separable Hilbert space $H$. Then for every operator $T$ in the strong closure of $A$, there is a sequence $T_n \in A$ such that $T_n \rightarrow T$ in the SOT" [The proof follows] "This corollary shows that in the separable case, the strong closure of a C*-Algebra of operators can be achieved by adjoining to the algebra all limits of its strongly convergent sequences."

And here I faint because I realize to have not understand at all what we did.

Isn't the strong closure of a C*-Algebra, by definition, the adjoining of all the limits of its strongly convergent sequences? Why a theorem is necessary?

Comment: I don't have Averson's book, but a guess is that he meant the formulation as found in Kehe Zhu (Theorem 19.5)
"The set of self-adjoint operators in B is the strong operator closure of the set of self-adjoint operators in A" where B is the strong operator closure of A. Does this seem plasubile?

Comment: Yes that's what Averson did too, but I still don't understand the conclusion I cited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strong operator topology on $\mathscr{B}(H)$ is not metrisable if the underlying Hilbert space $H$ is infinite-dimensional. Therefore it need not be [sequential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) *a priori*. What the Kaplansky density theorem really tells you is that elements in the SOT-closure of a C*-algebra are limits of (norm) bounded nets. Moreover, if the Hilbert space is separable, then bounded nets can be replaced with bounded *sequences*.

Answer (score 2):

Elements in the strong closure are only obviously limits of nets.  The Corollary
says that they are limits of sequences if the Hilbert space is separable.